# flexbox with images, fixed size

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I created this layout, its almost there but I'm struggling with the images and text beside it.  I want the entire box to flex at the same time, to keep the images and text responding at the same time.

What am I doing wrong? I think I am suffering from a mental block because this is my first time using flex.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1750px;
}

.venture,
#event-content,
#news-content {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  color: #444;
}

.catch {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1vmin 0vmin 0vmin 0vmin;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  background-color: #3366cc;
}

.tagline {
  margin-top: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 130%;
}

#news-content a:link,
#news-content a:hover,
#news-content a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  font-family: FG Font;
  font-size: 2vmin;
}

#news-content .btn.btn-primary {
  background-color: #3366cc;
  font-family: Arial;
  border-color: #3366cc;
}

#news-content .tag {
  background-color: #ef8b1e;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
  font-size: 1.5vmin;
  font-family: FG Font;
}

#news-content .title {
  padding: 25px 10px 0px 10px;
}

#event-content .date {
  background-color: #ef8b1e;
  font-family: FG Font;
  font-size: 3vmin;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: 70vh;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.main-wrapper>div {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 50vh;
}

.hero-img {
  display: flex;
}

.hero-img>div {
  margin: 1vmin;
  align-self: stretch;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.info-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.info-section .media-section {
  margin: 1vmin 0vmin;
}

.info-section .venture {
  position: relative;
  padding: 3vmin 3vmin 2vmin 3vmin;
}

.media-section>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.media-section>div>div {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

#news-content {
  margin-right: .5vmin;
}

#event-content {
  margin-left: .5vmin;
}

#news-content,
#event-content {
  max-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-wrapper">
    <div>
      <div class="hero-img">
        <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="img-fluid" alt="Allied Ship" /></div>
        <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="img-fluid" alt="Allied Ship" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="hero-img">
        <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="img-fluid" alt="Allied Air" /></div>
        <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="img-fluid" alt="Allied Helicopter" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="info-section">
        <div class="catch">
          <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="media-section">
          <div>
            <div id="news-content">
              <div class="tag">In the News</div>
              <div class="title"><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</a></div>
              <a href="">
                <div class="btn btn-primary">Link</div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div id="event-content">
              <div class="date">
                <div class="num">12</div>
                <div class="month">DEC</div>
              </div>
              <div class="details">
                <div class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
                <div class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="venture">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametn<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquam diam non mollis sollicitudin. Curabitur sed felis ac urna laoreet finibus nec eu sem. Fusce cursus tortor eget lectus lacinia, id blandit dolor ultrices. Aliquam pellentesque
            venenatis turpis, a viverra ante tincidunt vel. Quisque dui orci, viverra id ipsum eget, dictum mattis ante. Aliquam pellentesque massa et euismod efficitur. Aliquam vestibulum velit et lobortis feugiat. Curabitur vulputate quam efficitur,
            pellentesque ex quis, tincidunt orci. Donec magna est, ultrices nec pretium nec, porta id nisl. Mauris vitae magna ac sem pellentesque hendrerit. Donec elit justo, pulvinar id leo posuere, venenatis mattis nisl. Maecenas tristique augue ut
            odio tincidunt aliquam. Nullam volutpat lobortis eros.</p>
          <div class="tagline">LOREM IPSUM</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your images are not loading in your fiddle. Can you explain in more detail exactly how you want the images and text to behave?

Comment: "I want the entire box to flex at the same time, to keep the images and text responding at the same time." please clarify.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve nor what is wrong with the actual behaviour.

Comment: Sorry! the block of images is a 2 columns by 2 rows.  I am trying to make the entire block as one responsive unit.  Right now the images are expanding to be smaller than the right hand column.  I think it has to do with the my sizing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that you want, the entire container in same column can be done like that :

```
   <pre>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="main-wrapper">

                <div>
                    <div class="info-section">
                        <div>
                            <div class="hero-img">
                                <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="img-fluid" alt="Allied Ship" /></div>
                                <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="img-fluid" alt="Allied Ship" /></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="hero-img">
                                <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="img-fluid" alt="Allied Air" /></div>
                                <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="img-fluid" alt="Allied Helicopter" /></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="catch">
                            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-section">
                            <div>
                                <div id="news-content">
                                    <div class="tag">In the News</div>
                                    <div class="title"><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</a></div>
                                    <a href="">
                                        <div class="btn btn-primary">Link</div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div id="event-content">
                                    <div class="date">
                                        <div class="num">12</div>
                                        <div class="month">DEC</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="details">
                                        <div class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
                                        <div class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="venture">
                            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametn<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquam diam non mollis sollicitudin. Curabitur sed felis ac urna laoreet finibus nec eu sem. Fusce cursus tortor eget lectus lacinia, id blandit dolor ultrices. Aliquam pellentesque
                               venenatis turpis, a viverra ante tincidunt vel. Quisque dui orci, viverra id ipsum eget, dictum mattis ante. Aliquam pellentesque massa et euismod efficitur. Aliquam vestibulum velit et lobortis feugiat. Curabitur vulputate quam efficitur,
                               pellentesque ex quis, tincidunt orci. Donec magna est, ultrices nec pretium nec, porta id nisl. Mauris vitae magna ac sem pellentesque hendrerit. Donec elit justo, pulvinar id leo posuere, venenatis mattis nisl. Maecenas tristique augue ut
                               odio tincidunt aliquam. Nullam volutpat lobortis eros.</p>
                            <div class="tagline">LOREM IPSUM</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </pre>
```